# How to import external TypeScript file

Tags: typescript

It's possible to import JS file with TS declaration that's outside of TypeScript project. But it's impossible to import TS file that's outside of TypeScript project.

**Why? And how to overcome that?**

**Example:**

```
/shared-lib
  a.ts
  b.js
  b.d.ts

/my-project/
  app.ts
  tsconfig.json
```

- Try `../b' in`app.ts` - it works.
- Try `../a' in`app.ts` - it didn't, fails with the error.

The error:

```
error TS6059: File '.../a.ts' is not under 'rootDir' '.../my-project'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.
```

P.S.

This makes super hard to share files between projects, why it's impossible to do with `ts` but possible with `js & d.ts` which is derivative of `ts` is really strange...

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution to this problem? I am trying to import `interfaces.ts` which is compiled by an outside project and running into a similar problem.